# x64 masm setup in Jetbrain

Tags: assembly, x86-64, clion, masm, rider

How to develop x64/MASM application in JetBrains product?
If it is impossible, What is the proper way to develop/setup x64 masm coding in VS?

Sorry, I am totally a newbie on MASM.I recently receive a JetBrain Free License and I want to switch to JetBrain IDE,I am able to open the .sln created in VS on Rider but apparently there is no MASM/x64 support plugin. CLion doesnt even have the option create a ASM/MASM/x64 solution.

I used to follow a tutorial to setup a VS environment for MASM coding but I saw someone in Youtube mixing with C lang which makes me confuse

BTW, Can NASM run MASM? or NASM runs on x64?

Comment: In Visual Studio you can start by creating a C/C++ console application; right mouse click the project name select build customizations then build dependencies and enable the MASM target. You can then remove the C/C++ files and add assembly code .ASM file(s) to your project.

Comment: NASM is a separate x86-64 assembler that uses different syntax from MASM.  It reads a `.asm` file and creates a `.obj` (assuming you run `nasm -fwin64` rather than `-felf64` or `-fmacho64`, or `-fbin` to make a flat binary)...